# click function within another click function is called multiple times

Tags: javascript, jquery

i am in touch with jquery for the first time and ran into this: I am trying to create a dynamic input-form. A click function creates a new list-item with another click function nested into it (to provide a remove function for the clicked item).

When i execute the nested click function it appears to be called the number of instances that have been created of it.

Here is the code (i tried to remove as much as possible, but i am not quite sure where the error is - so i guess i left to much stuff in - sorry).

```
$("#addIngredient").click(function(e){
    e.preventDefault();

    var prefix = "form-"
    var last = $("#IngredientForm ul li").last().html();

    $("#IngredientForm ul").append("<li>"+last+"</li>");

    var name = $("#IngredientForm ul li:last input").attr("name");
    name = name.replace(prefix,'');
    var count = parseInt(name[0]);
    count += 1;


    $("#IngredientForm ul li:last input").attr("name",prefix+count+"-weight")
    $("#IngredientForm ul li:last select").attr("name",prefix+count+"-ingredient")
    $("#IngredientForm ul li:last input").attr("id","id_"+prefix+count+"-weight")
    $("#IngredientForm ul li:last select").attr("id","id_"+prefix+count+"-ingredient")
    $("#id_form-TOTAL_FORMS").val(count+1);

    $(".deleteIngredient").click(function(e){
        e.preventDefault();

        var aktuell = $(this).closest('li');
        var formCount;
        name = aktuell.children('input').attr("name");
        name = name.replace(prefix,'');
        counter = name.replace("-weight",'');
        formCount = parseInt($("#id_form-TOTAL_FORMS").val());

        aktuell.remove();
        --formCount;

        $("#id_form-TOTAL_FORMS").val(formCount);
        for (var i = parseInt(counter); i<formCount; i++){
        var newName = "form-"+(i);
        $("#id_form-"+(i+1)+"-weight").attr("name",newName+"-weight");
        $("#id_form-"+(i+1)+"-ingredient").attr("name",newName+"-ingredient");
        }

    });

 });
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This block

```
$(".deleteIngredient").click(function(e){...
```

attaches a clickevent to **all** `.deleteIngredient` elements, also those created before.

You have to put this block outsite the click event of `#addIngredient`. You can make the delete event to be attached also to every element added in the future.

```
$("#addIngredient").click(function(e){
    // ...
});

$(document).on("click", ".deleteIngredient", function(e){
    // ...
});
```

Comment: Yes this will probably work fine too, since the event handler seems to find it's parent `<li>` and work from that.

Answer (score 1):

As the other answers have noted, the click handler is adding a click handler to *every* `.deleteIngredient` element every time you run it, which adds multiple handlers to all the previous elements.

When you add a new item to the list, you don't have to add a click handler to it. You can use *delegation* to create a handler one time that will apply to dynamically-added elements:

```
$("#IngredientForm").on("click", ".deleteIngredient", function(e) {
    ...
});
```

See [Event binding on dynamically created elements?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/203198/event-binding-on-dynamically-created-elements) for more information.

Answer (score 0):

Every time that outer "click" event happens, you're adding *another* "click" handler for the ".deleteIngredient" element(s).  The `.click` function does not remove previously-assigned event handlers.

You can get rid of old handlers with `.unbind` or, preferably with new versions of jQuery, `.off`:

```
$('.deleteIngredient').unbind('click').click(function(event) {
  // ...
});
```

No, the thing is, here I *think* you probably want to bind to the `.deleteIngredient` button that you're adding for the new ingredient. The code you've got — based on the reference to `$('.deleteIngredient')` — will affect **all** of the elements on the page with that class. My guess here is that you're adding a button or something for each `<li>`. Thus, what you should probably be doing is finding the button inside the newly-added structure:

```
$('#IngredientForm ul li:last .deleteIngredient').click(function(event) {
  // ...
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Use this format instead

```
$("#addIngredient").on('click', function() {
   $(this).off();
});
```